# R & S Stereochemistry of an unsaturated ring system

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

> Using the *R*- & *S*- nomenclature assign a configurational symbol to decalin 4-methyl (above the plane), 4-hydroxy (below the plane), 7-isopropyl (above the plane), 1,9 diene. (Numbering the carbons in decalin ring-system: ring-junction carbons are 1 (top), 6 (bottom))
>
> [image: 2-methyl-8-(propan-2-yl)-1,2,3,4,7,8-hexahydronaphthalen-2-ol]

Carbon 7—holding the isopropyl group: I think this is *S* (isopropyl $ > \ce{C-C=C} > \ce{CH2} > \ce{CH}$).
Carbon 4—holding $\ce{CH3}$ & $\ce{OH}$: I think this is *S* ($\ce{OH}> \ce{CH3} > \ce{CH2=CH2}$).

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I have added a guessed structure diagram based on your description. However, your numbers of locants are not in accordance with this structure. In particular, the bridgehead atoms of decalin are actually not numbered 1 and 6.

Comment: Guess things have changed in 30-years. Numbering decalin, as I did, the 1-double bond is on the ring junction, otherwise the diagram is correct. Don't have a drawing package; and, given the silly prices of Chemdraw (a monthly subscription) am not likely to acquire one. All I require is the comfort of knowing my assignments are correct--if they are. Cheers.

Comment: @tony I changed the picture. Please check and confirm or rollback my edit.

Comment: Loong:yes, that's it: guess I'd better do something about presentation! Thanks. Cheers.

Comment: There are a number of free chemical drawing programs; just check the corresponding Wikipedia sites (if need really be I can find a link). But even if they are too much of a hassle, drawing on paper and scanning/taking a photo works, too.

Comment: @Loong Why didn’t you edit isopropyl in my answer, too? =C

Answer (score 1):

I don’t really know how you arrived at your reasoning, but it seems to fail as soon as double bonds are involved. If you encounter a double bond, it must be expanded with ghost atoms to two single bonds in the following manner:

$$\ce{(R2)C=C(R'2) -> (R2)C(C)-C(C)(R'2)}$$

The carbon atoms in bracket are ghost atoms not connected to anything else. These ghost atoms are treated just like normal atoms when determining priorities. You can read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules#Double_and_triple_bonds), which also includes a better graphic example. (But since your case is rather simple, we can do without.)

Let’s first determine the tertiary alcohol’s carbon’s absolute configuration:

1. $\ce{O}$ from the hydroxy group.
2. $\ce{C}$ (along the ring to the left)

   1. $\ce{C}$ (the quarternary carbon)

      - $\ce{C}$
      - $\ce{C}$ ← This is the first point of difference.
      - $\ce{(C)}$ — this is the double bond’s ghost atom.
   2. $\ce{H}$
   3. $\ce{H}$
3. $\ce{C}$ (along the ring upwards)

   1. $\ce{C}$

      - $\ce{C}$
      - $\ce{H}$ ← This is the first point of difference.
      - $\ce{H}$
   2. $\ce{H}$
   3. $\ce{H}$
4. $\ce{C}$ from the methyl group.

   1. $\ce{H}$
   2. $\ce{H}$
   3. $\ce{H}$

Thus, the priorities are $\ce{OH} > \ce{CH2C_{(q)}} > \ce{CH2CH2R} > \ce{CH3}$, because the quarternary carbon that one of the two $\ce{CH2}$ groups is bonded to beats the secondary carbon at the top of the right-hand ring. That makes that carbon’s absolute configuration (*S*).

Similarly, for the carbon attached to *iso*-propyl:

1. $\ce{C}$ (the quarternary carbon)

   1. $\ce{C}$
   2. $\ce{C}$
   3. $\ce{C}$
2. $\ce{C}$ (the *iso*-propyl group)

   1. $\ce{C}$
   2. $\ce{C}$
   3. $\ce{H}$
3. $\ce{C}$ (the secondary carbon)

   1. $\ce{C}$
   2. $\ce{H}$
   3. $\ce{H}$
4. $\ce{H}$

As you can see, we only need go down to the second level to find a difference: $\ce{C(C3)} > \ce{C(C2H)} > \ce{C(CH2)} > \ce{H}$ Thus, that carbon’s absolute configuration is (*R*).

Answer (score 0):

I think the carbon with the isopropyl group on it should be (*R*). The carbon at the ring fusion has highest priority because it has two real carbons and a phantom carbon from the double bond. This is higher priority than the two carbons and a hydrogen of the isopropyl group.